# Cannot use Subclipse after installing

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have installed Subclipse in Eclipse EE Luna.

This is what my installation details look like :

[image]

Going on past experience, I would now expect a silo icon to appear next to all of my files as they are locally all part of a SVN directory structure.

Also when I right click a file or folder I expect lots of SVN options. All I see is this :

[image]

Which leads me to believe that is not switched on? not working maybe?

Does anyone know what I need to do to get it working? Other SVN tools immediately synch up with my projects.

(The neverending Eclipse configuration nightmare continues....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that context menu for 'Team' if the current project is not being shared.

So right click on the Project and use 'Team > Share Project...' to set up the project in SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Subclipse cannot automatically connect to projects that existed in the workspace before you installed Subclipse.  For those projects, you have to use Team > Share Project. Subclipse will recognize that it is a SVN working copy and just "connect it".

That said, your option is grayed out.  That means these projects are already "connected" to a Team provider as far as Eclipse is concerned.  However, since there are no Team options on the menu, that means the team provider is likely not installed.

So my conclusion is that you had these projects linked to the Subversive plugin, not Subclipse.  You will have to install that plugin so you can use Team > Disconnect ... or you need to delete these projects and then re-import them to the workspace.